# Query DB field against a Texfield value?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm currently coding my login activity.
I want to test to see if the username the user has entered is in the database. So far i have...

```
EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_email);
EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);

String username = email.getText().toString();
String password = pass.getText().toString();

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

db.open();
Cursor u = db.getAllUsers();
if (username = .....)

//The getAllUsers is in the DBAdapter.java file.

public Cursor getAllUsers() 
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME}, null, null, null, null, null); 
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: in the ....  what is the code to search the database for the matching username ?

Comment: What is the content of the `getAllUsers` method?

Comment: in the DBApapter.java file it is coded as 

...
public Cusor getAllUsers()
{
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

basically i thought you would have to get all the users before you can compare with the username entered in the textfield.

Comment: Could you update your question with the `getAllUsers` method?

Comment: i have added the method.

Comment: *"I want to test to see if the username the user has entered is in the database"* - usually you treat a bad username and bad password as the same error condition. That is, you don't explicitly test if a user is present in the database. That keeps bad guys from using your database as an oracle to enumerate users.

Comment: once i know the code to test the username, I will also be testing the password. I just wanted to test the username first but thank you for your comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `db.getAllUsers` returns a `Cursor` object, you would need to iterate through it to get all the list of users in the database, as I have shown below:

```
ArrayList<String> someUsers = new ArrayList<String>();

if (u.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String aUser = u.getString(u.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME));
        someUsers.add(aUser);
    } while (u.moveToNext());
}
```

Then, you should check if the username entered by the user is in the generated list.

```
if (someUsers.contains(username)) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do something else
}
```